# Solving the transcendental equation $Li_{3}(e^{-kx}) + x\, Li_{2}(e^{-kx}) = k\, x^3$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers, transcendental-equations

I need to solve the following equation:

$Li_{3}(e^{-kx}) + x\, Li_{2}(e^{-kx}) = k\, x^3$

for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ and where $k\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Here $Li_{3}$ and $Li_{2}$ are the third and second polylogarithms. I have been able to show that the solution exists and it is unique, but I do not know how to continue further. In fact I am wondering about the very meaning of "solving the equation". What means solving an equation like this? I don't expect to solve it in terms of known transcendental functions, which takes me to my other question:

Is the inverse polylogarithm $Li^{-1}_{n}(z)$ defined? It is possible to solve the equation in terms of inverse polylogarithms?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that only numerical methods will be able to solve this monster. I hope for you that I am wrong !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: but what would mean solving it analitically? Solving it in terms of known trascendental functions? Can one invent a new transcendental function as naively the solution to that equation?

Comment: Yes, it is just simple : define the so-called $Bilateral\text{_}Function(k)$ which is the solution of your equation ! I am just kidding you, be sure. Back to serious, I do not see any hope beside numerical methods. There no inverse of  polylogarithms, so ... Even if one did exist ...

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: why there is no inverse of polylogarithm?